# Conditionally render screen based on authenticated user in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to conditionally render a React Native screen dependent on whether 1) the screen is loading whilst the app checks for authentication status 2) the user is already authenticated thereby displaying the home screen 3) the user is not authenticated thereby displaying the login/signup screen.

I've been largely success implementing this, however, in the case of (2), the Signup screen is very briefly displayed until the correct Homepage screen is shown.. which is annoying. Here is my code:

```
const App = () => {
    const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false)
    const [user, setUser] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
        const checkAuth = async () => {
            try {
                await Auth.getCurrentAuthenticatedUser()
                    .then(user => setUser(user))
            } catch (e) {
                console.log('An error occurred.. ', e)
            }
        }
        checkAuth()
        setIsReady(true)
    }, [])

    const showAppLoading = (!isReady && !user)
    
    if (showAppLoading) {
        // App is loading
        view = <LoadingComponent />
    } else if (!user) {
        // User not authenticated - go to Authenticator
        view = <AuthNavigator />
    } else {
        // User is authenticated - go to App
        view = <App signOut={signOut} />
    }

    return (
        <View>{view}</View>
    )
}
```

It appears that `<AuthNavigator />` loads briefly because `user` state hasn't loaded in time, however, I don't know why this is because `setUser()` has been called straight after I get the user credentials.

Hope you can help

Comment: Not sure how the second `else if` (or `showAppLoading`) condition ever succeeds because `user` is set to `{}` initially which is **truthy** and so `!user` will be `false`. Also execution of `setIsReady(true)` will not wait for `checkAuth()` to complete first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way.

```
useEffect(() => {
        try {
            Auth.getCurrentAuthenticatedUser()
                .then(user => {
                    setUser(user);
                    setIsReady(true);
                });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('An error occurred.. ', e)
        }
    
    }, [])
```